# Auto layout Failed to Render

Tags: xcode, autolayout, simulator, tvos, xcode7-beta2

I have been getting this error only on occasion when I work on my storyboard:

```
  Failed to render and update auto layout status for Category 
  ViewController: IBAppleTVSimulatorAgent.app failed to launch
```

I usually just close and reopen my xcode and the warning goes away, but could someone please tell me as to why this is happening and how I can have a more permanent solution rather than just restarting my xcode?

Thaaaanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a glitch in Xcode 7.1 beta 2 when laying out tvOS storyboards. It's just something to put up with until they fix it, hopefully in beta 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue while developing TV app.

I deleted the Xcode 7.1 beta 2 and 
I reinstall the Xcode 7.1 beta 2

this fixed my problem.